# Cant get the length of a music in wxpython

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, wxpython, mplayer

i am trying to build a music player using wxpython, mPlayerCtrl. But i am having a issue n getting the length of the added music. I have tried:

```
self.mplayer.Length()
```

when I am using .Length() its giving error

> AttributeError: 'MplayerCtrl' object has no attribute 'Length'

```
self.mplayer.length()
```

And ehen i am using .length() its giving error

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

```
t_len = self.mplayer.GetTimeLength()
self.playbackSlider.SetRange(0, t_len)
```

This gives an error

> TypeError: Slider.SetRange(): argument 2 has unexpected type
>   'NoneType'

my code is as belows

```
if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        path = dlg.GetPath()
        self.currentFolder = os.path.dirname(path[0])
        trackPath = '"%s"' % path.replace("\\", "/")
        self.mplayer.Loadfile(trackPath)
        t_len = self.mplayer.GetTimeLength()
        self.playbackSlider.SetRange(0, t_len)
        self.playbackTimer.Start(100.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to call `GetProperty` in order to get media length:

```
length = self.mplayer.GetProperty('length')
```

Refer the full list of properties [here](https://pythonhosted.org/MplayerCtrl/reference.html#reference-props)

Comment: GetProperty() is returning None type

Comment: @MdToufique I suspect that you will need to have started the video BEFORE calling `length = self.mplayer.GetProperty('length')`, unless mplayer is psychic :)

Comment: ohh ok ..    thnks :)